# Parse dict into a dict python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON file which looks like this :

```
{"@count": 476, "@start": 1, "@totalcount": 476, "Messages": [],   
 "ResourceName": "Incident",   "ReturnCode": 0, "content": [
 {"Incident": {"IncidentID": "I08000003"}},
 {"Incident": {"IncidentID": "I08000157"}},
 {"Incident": {"IncidentID": "I08000274"}} }
```

When i try

```
json_obj = json.load(response) for i in json_obj['content']:
```

I get all the lines, but I just want to get the numbers (I08000003,I08000157..)

How can I do please ?

Comment: You want to get a list of all the `incidentID` attributes?

Comment: Exactly, as i said only the incidentID  (I08000003,I08000157..)

Comment: The JSON content you provided is invalid – the parens are unbalanced, and a closing square bracket is missing somewhere (probably close to the end).

Comment: @dudzer please come back and provide feedback on the answers you have received.

Answer (score 0):

You need to not only parse the input, but then collect the `IncidentID`s

```
import json

content = #your json file content as a string
data = json.loads(content)
ids = []
for incident in data['content']:
    ids.push(incident['Incident']['IncidentID'])
print(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out jsonpath.  Probably the library you want for this sort of data extraction:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath-ng/1.4.2

That's a next gen link.  i believe there is a base version of it too.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved :

> response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
>
> content=response.read()
>
> data = json.loads(content) ids = [] for incident in data['content']:
>       print(incident['Incident']['IncidentID'])

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
json_data = json.load(open("xyz.json", "r"))

final_list = [x["Incident"]["IncidentID"] for x in json_data["content"] if "Incident" in x and "IncidentID" in x["Incident"]]

for data in final_list: print data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using comprehension -

```
>>> test_dict = {"@count": 476, "@start": 1, "@totalcount": 476, "Messages": [],   
             "ResourceName": "Incident",   "ReturnCode": 0, "content": [
             {"Incident": {"IncidentID": "I08000003"}},
             {"Incident": {"IncidentID": "I08000157"}},
             {"Incident": {"IncidentID": "I08000274"}}]}

>>> [incident 
     for incident in row['Incident'].values() 
     for row in test_dict['content']]

['I08000274', 'I08000274', 'I08000274']
```